# How to cancel or pause a urllib request in python

Tags: python, tkinter, urllib, urllib3, python-3.8

So I have this program which requests a file from the web and the user can download it. I am using **urllib.request and tkinter** for my program. The problem is that when the user hits the 'Download' button there is no pause or cancel until the file gets downloaded and the program freezes too. I really want to create a pause or a cancel button, but I do not know how and I want to eliminate the freezing of the program. Should I use another library like 'requests'? Or should I try threading? Can someone guide me through this?
My code(BTW if you know any way to improve my program I would appreciate it a lot if you shared it with me):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkFont
import random
import urllib.request
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
from tqdm.auto import tqdm


def printsth():
    print("Yay it works! ")


def main_menu():
    root = Tk()
    # the top menu
    num = IntVar()
    # var = IntVar()
    menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    submenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=submenu)

    def custom_op():
        custom = Tk()

        custom.mainloop()
    submenu.add_command(label="Customization ", command=custom_op)

    def settings_op():
        set_win = Tk()

        set_win.mainloop()
    submenu.add_command(label="Settings ", command=settings_op)
    submenu.add_separator()
    submenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)

    # the edit menu
    editmenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Redo...", command=printsth)

    # the tool bar
    toolbar = Frame(root, bg="light gray")
    insert_button = Button(toolbar, text="Insert an image", command=printsth)
    insert_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
    print_button = Button(toolbar, text="Print", command=printsth)
    print_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
    toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

    # the download function
    def download_image():
        global formatname
        if num.get() == 1:
            name = random.randrange(1, 100000)
        else:
            name = str(name_entry.get())
        formatname = str(format_entry.get())
        '''if var.get() == 1:
            operator = str(url_entry.get())
            formatname = '.' + operator[-3] + operator[-2] + operator[-1]
        else:
            pass'''
        fullname = str(name) + formatname
        url = str(url_entry.get())
        fw = open('file-size.txt', 'w')
        file_size = int(requests.head(url, headers={'accept-encoding': ''}).headers['Content-Length'])
        fw.write(str(file_size))
        fw.close()
        path = str(output_entry.get()) + "\\"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path.replace("\\", "\\\\") + fullname)

    # the status bar
    status_bar = Label(root, text="Downloading...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
    status_bar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    # the download frame
    body_frame = Frame(root, bg="light blue")
    download_button = Button(body_frame, text="Download! ", command=download_image, border=3, width=20, height=5)
    download_design = tkFont.Font(size=12, slant='italic')
    download_button['font'] = download_design
    download_button.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=5)
    body_frame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    # the main interaction menu
    inter_frame = Frame(root)
    url_entry = Entry(inter_frame)
    label = Label(inter_frame, text="Enter the image URL: ")
    file_format = Label(inter_frame, text="Choose your file format: ")
    format_entry = Entry(inter_frame)
    file_name = Label(inter_frame, text="File's name: ")
    name_entry = Entry(inter_frame)
    check_name = Checkbutton(inter_frame, text="Give a random name", variable=num)
    # check_format = Checkbutton(inter_frame, text="Download with default format", variable=var)
    output_path = Label(inter_frame, text="Choose output path: ")
    output_entry = Entry(inter_frame)
    file_name.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    name_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    check_name.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    label.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    url_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    file_format.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    format_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    # check_format.pack(anchor=CENTER)
    output_path.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    output_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    inter_frame.pack(expand=1)
    root.mainloop()

    # the end!


main_menu()
```

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045508/7414759)

Comment: You can associate a callback to `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` via `reporthook` option and abort the download by raising exception inside the callback.

Comment: Can you give an example?(like a code sample)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reporthook` option of `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` to associate a callback and abort the download by raising exception inside the callback:

```
downloading = False   # flag to indicate whether download is active

def download_progress(count, blksize, filesize):
    nonlocal downloading
    if downloading:
        downloaded = count * blksize
        print('downloaded %s / %s' % (downloaded, filesize))
        root.update()  # let user interact with the GUI
    else:
        # user selects to abort the download
        raise Exception('download aborted!')

# the download function
def download_image():
    global formatname
    nonlocal downloading
    if downloading:
        downloading = False
        return
    download_button.config(text='Stop!')  # let user to click the button to abort download
    downloading = True
    if num.get() == 1:
        name = random.randrange(1, 100000)
    else:
        name = str(name_entry.get())
    formatname = str(format_entry.get())
    '''if var.get() == 1:
        operator = str(url_entry.get())
        formatname = '.' + operator[-3] + operator[-2] + operator[-1]
    else:
        pass'''
    fullname = str(name) + formatname
    url = str(url_entry.get())
    fw = open('file-size.txt', 'w')
    file_size = int(requests.head(url, headers={'accept-encoding': ''}).headers['Content-Length'])
    fw.write(str(file_size))
    fw.close()
    path = str(output_entry.get()) + "\\"
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path.replace("\\", "\\\\")+fullname, download_progress)  # added reporthook callback
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)  # download aborted
    else:
        print('done')
    download_button.config(text='Download!')  # resume download button
```

*The text of `download_button` is changed to `Stop!` after it is clicked so that user can click it again to abort the download.  When the download is aborted/completed, its text is changed back to "Download!".*

Comment: Hello, acw1668. I have tried your code but I get a Syntax error like this one: SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'downloading' found. So is there any solution to this problem?